# Accepting same password in both upper and lower case

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am facing a strange issue now. I have a login page in ASP.NET MVC which accepts username and password from the user.
When user clicks on Login button, the form is submitted back to the controller with the entered data.

Then I use below code to check if it is a valid login :

```
var isValidLogin = (from user in dbEntities.usermasters
                     where (user.userName.Equals(login.username) && user.password.Equals(login.password))
                     select user).Any();
```

`isValidLogin` is returning `true` for both cases. ie if the password is `pwd` and user enteres `PWD` it is returning `true`.
Would appreciate some valuable suggestions.

Comment: have you checked collation of your database ?

Comment: I don't know what the problem is but saving passwords in plaintext is really bad.

Comment: @nbokmans : I am planning to use password hashing in the next phase.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad : How?

Comment: I'd recommend not to implement the authentication mechanism on your own but use ASP.NET Identity instead (https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)

Comment: @samwise : Thank you. Point noted.

Answer (score 3):

I think SQL Server's default collation is case-insensitive. You can set the collation at a server, table or column level.

To check your server collaction:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('COLLATION')
```

In my case, it's: `Latin1_General_CI_AS`. This CI stands for case insensitive.

You may be confused about `string.Equals` being case insensitive but it's actually converted to a query in LINQ to Entities.

You can change the collation of the password column to case sensitive one if you want.

**PS**

It's really not recommended to store passwords in plaintext. If you're database, or it's backup gets compromised, you're doomed. The recomendation is storing them as salted hashes. Everytime the user logs in, you apply the hash + salt to the password and compare it with what is stored in the database. Hashes are not reversible.

Also, if you use hashes, it will be case sensitive as a bonus :)

Comment: I guess you could force the check to happen in code using `String.Equals(user.userName, login.username)` also (?)

Comment: @Mackan, that would trigger an exception because LINQ wouldn't know how to convert it to SQL. In order to check it in code, do it after materialization (.ToList())

Comment: Thanks. I will check.

Comment: Ah, yes .. obviously not right in the linq statement :) +1